# factories within services in angular- load order issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

In my angular code, to avoid code duplication, I inject a same factory into multiple services. At first, when I did this it started throwing errors `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider`

After some debugging, it became obvious that this was a load order issue. To get around it, in my `build.config.js` file, I changed `module.exports.app_files.js` so that factories were loaded before services.

My build.config.js file now has this in it

```
module.exports = {
build_dir: 'build'
compile_dir: 'bin',
app_files: {
modules: [
    'src/**/*.js',
    '!src/**/*.spec.js',
    '!src/**/*-service.js',
    '!src/**/*-controller.js',
    '!src/**/*-config.js',
    '!src/**/*-directive.js',
    '!src/**/*-factory.js',
    '!src/**/*-filter.js',
    '!src/**/*-run.js'
],
js: [
    'src/**/*-factory.js',
    'src/**/*-service.js',
    'src/**/*-controller.js',
    'src/**/*-config.js',
    'src/**/*-directive.js',
    'src/**/*-filter.js',
    'src/**/*-run.js',
    '!src/**/*.spec.js'
],
...
```

The source code of the angular application is [here](https://tuleap.net/plugins/git/tuleap/tuleap/stable?p=tuleap%2Fstable.git&a=tree&hb=77b26e8603fe3e4336b45b8f6b1482161972b3db&h=09cb2cbec8dc7a81e161ec94ce71c2e2fa5b6540&f=plugins/agiledashboard/www/js/angular) and the modification is [here](http://gerrit.tuleap.net/#/c/3285/)

It would seem that I'm forced to have a hierarchy and that I could never have a factory-named file that has a dependence on a service named file. Whether one should or shouldn't is not the debate here; I'm more concerned about the hierarchy.

I would like to know if there is an alternative way around this?

[edit] : I think I have found the source of the problem (fingers crossed that it stays fixed). I was developing using `grunt watch`. However, when I stopped the process and simply ran `grunt`, everything is happy again. Thanks to the people below for asking questions and ascertaining that this was not normal behaviour!

Comment: There should be no load order dependence between factories and services. I suspect something else is going on. Is it possible your loading a factory/service after your app has been bootstrapped?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Where are you getting that error? What is the source code? It will obviously be at some Dependency Injection point, but what is the code calling it? And what is the unknown provider?

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have added a link to the source code and the problem seems to be solved (see edit).